# Checking dates from a range in an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a function that takes in an array and searches to see if an employee was hired after 1990. If they were the function will push their name to a new array. I am dealing with age ranges so I am getting a bit tripped up with filtering. I came up with a pretty sneaky way around this by copying the first 4 values in the key pair to a third compare array. My code seems to work as expected but is throwing a random error message and I am not sure how to debug it. Is there a more efficient way of accomplishing the same result that will not result in an error message?

```js
const employeeList = [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Employee 1",
    "years": "1991 - 1993",
    "nationality": "Asian"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Employee 2",
    "years": "1988 - 2020",
    "nationality": "Hispanic"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Employee 3",
    "years": "1990 - 2010",
    "nationality": "Pacific Islander"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Employee 4",
    "years": "1971 - 1999",
    "nationality": "Asian"
  }
]

function getEmployees(array) {
  let newArray = new Array();
  let compareArray = new Array();
  for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    compareArray.push((array[i].years).substr(0, 4));
  }
  console.log(compareArray)
  for (var j = 0; j < compareArray.length; j++) {
    console.log(compareArray[j])
    console.log(array[j].name)
    if (compareArray[j] > 1990) {
      newArray.push.call(array[j].name);
    }
  }
  return (newArray);
}

getEmployees(employeeList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with your usage of [`.call()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=call%20MDN&oq=call%20MDN&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.3077j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). The first argument to `.call()` specifies what the `this` binding will be for the method you're using `.call()` on. In this case, you're setting the this to be your string `array[j].name`. When `.push()` runs it will try and update the array you're pushing to's `.length` property (so the `this`'s .length property). As you're setting the `this` to be a string, when .push() tries to update the `.length` property of the string it will throw an error since the `.length` property of a string is read-only, meaning that you cannot assign new values to it.

Instead, you want the `this` to refer to your new array, not your string. Instead, you can use:

```
.call(newArray, array[j].name)
```

or instead, just use:

```
newArray.push(array[j].name);
```

```js
const employeeList = [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Employee 1",
    "years": "1991 - 1993",
    "nationality": "Asian"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Employee 2",
    "years": "1988 - 2020",
    "nationality": "Hispanic"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Employee 3",
    "years": "1990 - 2010",
    "nationality": "Pacific Islander"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Employee 4",
    "years": "1971 - 1999",
    "nationality": "Asian"
  }
]

function getEmployees(array) {
  let newArray = [];
  let compareArray = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    compareArray.push(+(array[i].years).substr(0, 4));
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < compareArray.length; j++) {
    if (compareArray[j] > 1990) {
      newArray.push(array[j].name); // change to just `.push()` rather than `.call()`
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(getEmployees(employeeList));
```

Comment: Thank you everybody for your responses. I tried to upvote everyone but since I am new the upvotes are not public. I just learned about .map, .filter, and .reduce. That would have definitely helped with this task. I really liked Nick Parsons' explanation of my original code line. Thank you again for answering everybody!

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do the same thing as following:

```
employeeList.filter((employee) =>
                    Number(employee["years"].substr(0, 4)) > 1990)
    .map(employee => employee["name"])
```

I think it's more readable, personally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do without the intermediate array:

```
employeeList.filter(e => parseInt(e.years.replace(/ .*$/, '')) > 1990).map(e => e.name)
```

**filter** will return an array with only values matching the expression and **map** will return a new array with each element replaced by the result of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished more simply using `Array#filter` to find the employees who started after 1990 and `Array#map` to obtain only the names.

```js
const employeeList = [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Employee 1",
    "years": "1991 - 1993",
    "nationality": "Asian"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Employee 2",
    "years": "1988 - 2020",
    "nationality": "Hispanic"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Employee 3",
    "years": "1990 - 2010",
    "nationality": "Pacific Islander"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Employee 4",
    "years": "1971 - 1999",
    "nationality": "Asian"
  }
];
const res = employeeList.filter(({years})=>+years.slice(0,4)>1990).map(({name})=>name);
console.log(res);
```